# Expand all collapsible sections for text search

Tags: javascript, html

We have an existing page that contains collapsed list items. The problem is that if someone tries to search the text on the page no results are found for any item that is currently collapsed. I've searched and it seems that browsers just can't search into collapsed items.

As a potential workaround I figured I could try to add a listener for the Ctrl+F key press that would then open all of the collapsed items (if there is a better solution for this let me know). This would then allow the text to be searched.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) {
    document.getElementById('accordion1').click();
    //would like to make all accordians expand when Ctrl+F is pressed so that content can be searched
  }
```

While I can add a listener for the keypress (using the above code), I can't seem to figure out how to make all of the collapsed elements open.

I did not write the original code for this page. I could rewrite the entire page with different code that would work but I was hoping that there is a simpler solution since the live page has many more sections and would take me many hours to rewrite everything. I've created a simplified example of our page (removed all main content to make a smaller sample) here https://jsfiddle.net/felipeseiber/886p4eps/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out what to do. Just modified the JS to the following and it worked.

```
(function() {
  var d = document,
    accordionToggles = d.querySelectorAll('.js-accordionTrigger'),
    setAria,
    setAccordionAria,
    switchAccordion,
    touchSupported = ('ontouchstart' in window),
    pointerSupported = ('pointerdown' in window);
  skipClickDelay = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.click();
  }

  setAriaAttr = function(el, ariaType, newProperty) {
    el.setAttribute(ariaType, newProperty);
  };

  setAccordionAria = function(el1, el2, expanded) {
    switch (expanded) {
      case "true":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'true');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'false');
        break;
      case "false":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'false');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'true');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  switchAccordion = function(e) {
    console.log("triggered");
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisAnswer = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    var thisQuestion = e.target;
    if (thisAnswer.classList.contains('is-collapsed')) {
      setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'true');
    } else {
      setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'false');
    }
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('animateIn');
  };

  expandAccordion = function(target) {
    console.log("triggered");
    var thisAnswer = target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    var thisQuestion = target;
    if (thisAnswer.classList.contains('is-collapsed')) {
      setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'true');
      thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
      thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
      thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
      thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
      thisAnswer.classList.toggle('animateIn');
    }
  };

  for (var i = 0, len = accordionToggles.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (touchSupported) {
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('touchstart', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    if (pointerSupported) {
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('pointerdown', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('click', switchAccordion, false);
  }
})();

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) {
    //document.getElementById('accordion1').click();
    //alert("Expand all collapsed sections for search");
    //would like to make all accordians expand when Ctrl+F is pressed so that content can be searched
    var accordionToggles = document.querySelectorAll('.js-accordionTrigger');
    for (var i = 0, len = accordionToggles.length; i < len; i++) {
            expandAccordion(accordionToggles[i]);    
    }
  }
})
```

It's possible the other answer may have also worked but I did not try it myself since I've found a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Comments in the code.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) {
    // Store all accordion trigger elements
    var d = document,
    accordionToggles = d.querySelectorAll('.js-accordionTrigger');
    // loop through all accordion trigger elements
    for (var i = 0, len = accordionToggles.length; i < len; i++) {
      // store the current iterated accordion tigger element and content
      var thisAnswer = accordionToggles[i].parentNode.nextElementSibling;
      var thisQuestion = accordionToggles[i];
      // check if current iterated accordion content has a class of "is-collapsed".
      if (thisAnswer.classList.contains('is-collapsed')) {
        // toggle current iterated accordion trigger and content classes if condition is met
        thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
        thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
        thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
        thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
        thisAnswer.classList.toggle('animateIn');
      }
    }
  }
})
```